# execute bash if else command in php ( bash vs php )

Tags: php, bash, shell, exec

**What i want to achieve** 
I want to execute some script it it's process in not started on the server. so for that i am preparing the command in shell script and executing it in single line.

**Command with php variable**

```
$cmd = "if [[ `ps auxww | grep -v grep | grep ".$process_file." | grep '".$find."'`  == '' ]] ; then ".$cmd2."  fi";

echo $cmd."\n";
```

**Executed command, once variables are replaced (what will actually run on bash):**

```
if [[ `ps auxww | grep -v grep | grep /home/new_jig.php | grep 'test_51 1714052'`  == '' ]] ; then  php /home/new_jig.php test_51 1714052 & fi;
```

**executing command**

```
exec($cmd,$out,$res);
```

Please note that, I have also split the problem in to two statement and execute those.  But it is time consuming.  It is causing problems when I have more than 2000 in list, and the command is executed for all.  This takes about 1 or more than 1 minute to reach to the last number.

I want to achieve this within 10 seconds. Please help me to reach optimum output.

Thanks
Jignesh

Comment: _"I want to achieve this within 10 seconds"_ - Any specific reason for that magic number? You might also want to explain what the script actually does? You also seem to be executing some PHP code in your bash script. What does that script do?

Comment: we have one daemon process with runs every 3 seconds which trigger multiple php processes ( 2000+). to do some data fetching from third party websites. Currently problem is, it is taking more than a minutes to reach till end if i use followings...  $cmd = "ps auxww | grep -v grep | grep ".$process_file." | grep ".$find." > /dev/null 2>&1";   exec($cmd,$out,$res); and based on the result i execute  something like ... php /home/new_jig.php test_51 1714052

Comment: @Nic3500 - Isn't that package making shell commands as well? So basically, it would simply just move the call from one place to another? And regarding `grep`, `if then else`, I doubt that it will make any performance difference if those are in PHP vs CLI.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson; indeed, it could be, I did not dig in the code.  CLI has to start a shell to run every command, processing text (or arrays here) is much faster in PHP, than starting a bunch of shells.  I sometimes rewrite long bash scripts into Perl (or other), and the difference is crazy!  Hence my suggestion to do as little in bash as possible when speed is a concern.

Comment: @Nic3500 - I totally agree with using some other language for managing processes. PHP isn't really optimized for that. Just wanted to point out that the package you recommended also does CLI-calls, so there aren't much to gain by using that instead :-)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson: indeed, I removed my comment, rewrite follows.

Comment: To cut processing time, you need to do as much as you can in PHP, and reduce the number of shell commands.  But why use PHP at all to manage processes? If speed is critical, look at building or finding something in C.

Comment: my application is php and shall script base. so i thought to reduce php function and start combining functionality on shall to see how it sounds.

Comment: I also come across.... but it is not working as expected, ps auxww | grep -v grep | grep /home/new_jig.php && php /home/new_jig.php test_51 1714052  . Here with && if first command executes then only the next command executes. i don't want output, but i want conditional execution, if from first command ( process is not running on server then only)  execute the next command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

somehow I am able to make it execute with the following command

$process_file = phpfile which executing some functionality

$cmd2 = " `php ".$process_file." 1212 >/dev/null 2>/dev/null &` ";

$cmd11 ="if `ps -auxw | grep -v grep | grep '".$process_file."' | grep '".$find."' &> /dev/null` ; then echo 1;".$cmd2."; fi";

shell_exec($cmd11." >/dev/null 2>/dev/null &");

Before this: for 1100 request the process was taking about **60+ seconds**
After this: it is getting completed between **20 to 30 seconds**